# How to get the language and geo of the campaign?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to get the language and target geo of the campaign,but I can not find the relevent field from Google Ads Query Builder,could you give me some help,
Thanks.

Comment: please add more description so that the community members can get better understanding of your query.